# ImportXML in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to scrape a very specific text field from an Italian library website via Google Sheets, but -- despite my previously successful scrapes from other webpages on this website -- can't seem to figure this one out.

Here's an example webpage for one Italian periodical I'm interested in gathering data on: http://digitale.bnc.roma.sbn.it/tecadigitale/giornale/RML0027063/1928/unico

The field I'm looking to scrape (for about 2,500 entries) is: "Luoghi" (which refers to the place(s) where the periodical was published). I am not interested in the text "Luoghi" but rather the text that appears in the space beneath the title "Luoghi," which in the above provided webpage is "Roma." That text will change, of course, from publication to publication.

I went and retrieved the Xpath for this specific text field, which Google Chrome says is the following: `//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/dl/dd[7]`

Then I changed the double quotes to single quotes, like this: `//*[@id='main']/div[2]/div[2]/div/dl/dd[7]`

And then I placed it into an IMPORTXML command, like this: `=IMPORTXML("http://digitale.bnc.roma.sbn.it/tecadigitale/giornale/RML0027063/1928/unico","//*[@id='main']/div[2]/div[2]/div/dl/dd[7]")`

But it just gives me an error for some reason. As was mentioned above, I have been able to scrape from this website before, albeit from ordered lists and not divs, as is the case with this example. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks so much.

-- Cavallo Scuro

Answer (score 0):

Try with this xpath

```
//div[@class='data-detail']/dl/dd[7]
```

if you use

```
//div[@class='data-detail']/dl/dt|//div[@class='data-detail']/dl/dd
```

you will get all details, and you can then take the line you wish for instance line 14 by

```
=index(importxml(url,"//div[@class='data-detail']/dl/dt|//div[@class='data-detail']/dl/dd"),14,1)
```